# Error: Problem with node not being found using enzyme. Method text

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing a small test for a PopUp component. However, I am getting this error: Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. I am in the learning process, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
This is my component.tests.js

```
        const small = popUp.find('small');
        expect(small).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(small.text()).toBe(messages['en'] . 
        ['segments.create.timeline.isScheduled']);
        expect(warning).toBeDefined();
        expect(popover).toBeDefined();
        expect(message).toBeDefined();       
    });
});
```

And this is my component.js

```
class SegmentWarningPopup extends React.Component {
    state = {
        anchorEl: null,
    };

    handleClick = event => {
        this.setState({
            anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
        });
    };

    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            anchorEl: null,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { anchorEl } = this.state;
        const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

        return (
            <div>
                <Warning size="small" className="duration-has-changed-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
                <Popover
                    id="durationHasChanged"
                    open={open}
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'bottom',
                        horizontal: 'left',
                    }}

                    transformOrigin={{
                        vertical: 'top',
                        horizontal: 'left',
                    }}

                    PaperProps={{
                        className: 'warning-popover-paper'
                    }}
                >
                    <FormattedMessage id={"segments.create.timeline.isScheduled"} description="text"/>
                </Popover>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

    SegmentWarningPopup.propTypes = {
    targetEventObj: PropTypes.object
};

    export default SegmentWarningPopup;
```

Comment: are you trying to find the `<Warning>` component?

Comment: Yes I am trying to find that component

Comment: I suggest that you look at [the documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/). In particular, you need to read how the `find()` method works and what parameters it accepts. Also, please post a [mcve]. Your test is missing `it()` and a few other details.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `.find` the `<Warning>` component itself:

```
  popUp.find(Warning)
```